# Шифрование данных перед отправкой на сервер

Tags: html, php, шифрование, mysql

Привет! Задача следующая: необходимо шифровать данные из полей html-формы перед отправкой на сервер, а там их расшифровывать и пихать в mySQL. Сколько гуглил - ничего более-менее внятного так и не нашел по этой теме... Проблема состоит вся в том, что пользоваться можно лишь php, html + mySQL запросы... Может кто-нибудь подсказать, каким образом это можно организовать!?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте HTTPS. Сертификат на 1 год можно бесплатно получить (и бесплатно же продлять) у StartSSL.

Не стоит делать свое шифрование на JavaScript, оно только . Вот, что по этому поводу подробно и правильно пишут специалисты (конкретно, Nate Lawson): http://rdist.root.org/2010/11/29/final-post-on-javascript-crypto/.

Answer (score 0):

Гуглите реализацию el-gamal в качестве установки безопасного канала, потом RSA в качестве шифрования. По безопасному каналу передается ключ RSA. Ключ надо довольно часто менять.

Comment: https насколько далека от Вашего совета ?

Comment: по смыслу - не очень далека. Но там другой принцип шифрования немножко. =) Он сложнее реализуем

Answer (score 0):

а почему бы обратимые алгоритмы шифрования не использовать или не шифровать, сделав ключевым последнее введенное слово? Всё это вполне реально и алгоритмы давно ясны и реализованы!

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, какие слова надо писать на html, чтобы браузер данные формы перед отправкой шифровал.

Comment: чем php для реализации данной задачи не подходит? В вопросе ясно указано "html, php, mysql"

Comment: Ну, прочитав в вопросе "**необходимо шифровать данные из полей html-формы перед отправкой на сервер, а там их расшифровывать и пихать в mySQL**", я решил, что передача между браузером и php должна быть шифрована. 

А как следует понимать вопрос ?

Comment: Лично я за https

Comment: Да, "передача между браузером и php должна быть шифрована", вы правильно поняли...я так понимаю тут надо использовать javascript, чтобы шифровать данные на компе и в шифрованном виде отправлять? просто в моем понимании заложено: php выполняется на сервере, т.е. php должен уже шифрованные данные отсылать в sql-запрос!?

у меня было так: 
при помощи php получаем данные из полей, и тут уже шифровать смысла нет, т.к. это уже на сервере выполняется...выходит надо на компе это делать, и тут - яваскрипт...!?

Comment: почитаю еще про https...спасибо